# AWS security can it be more confusing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I read AWS docs on python and AssumeRole operation and stumble upon these lines which looks to me like a total security hole - "Notmally would not have access to" , what am i missing ?

> Returns a set of temporary security credentials that you can use to access AWS resources that you might not normally have access to. These temporary credentials consist of an access key ID, a secret access key, and a security token

from here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

i just don't understand some basic stuff - someone told me to use AssumeRole instead of keeping credentials in home folder (~/.aws)
but reading the boto docs about credentials reveals that in order to perform assumerole i still need credentials - so why to bother and assume a role , i can just give my access_key the right permissions and thats it no ?

```
# In ~/.aws/credentials:
[development]
aws_access_key_id=foo
aws_access_key_id=bar

# In ~/.aws/config
[profile crossaccount]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:...
source_profile=development
```

here is the docs
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials

Comment: If your question is about the security concepts of AWS, then this might not be the right forum for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: ***yes*, AWS security - both the concepts and practices - *can* be more confusing** especially when you're first learning about security in the cloud. Computer security practices that you might be used to outside the cloud often seem weird and opaque when applied to the context of cloud, however a lot of the time the underlying concepts hold true no matter where they're applied.

Secondly, **there is no security hole in the AssumeRole mechanism**. It was designed like this to adhere to the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), a universally accepted concept in computer security. The idea being that a particular entity (such as a developer or computer program) only be granted enough power to perform a finite set of operations.

For example, let's say I'm one of many developers contracted by a large company to build a social media app in their AWS infrastructure. The company gives me access keys that only have power over their EC2 instances (creating, deleting, etc) and S3 buckets. They make me assume a special role, `DatabaseOperator`, when I need to perform database maintenance. And they allow security auditors to audit their system with the role `ApplicationSecurityAuditor`. Every other resource in AWS is denied by virtue of them not being granted in the roles, therefore these roles give the people using them **access to resources they would not normally have**.

You asked "*why would I bother with multiple roles when I can just assign permissions to the user and be done with it?*". You can do this and there's nothing inherently bad about it. If your development environment is small enough and you can keep track of which users have certain permissions assigned then you may forego the overhead of separate roles.

However, this approach doesn't scale well and has serious security and maintenance implications:

- you no longer have *fine-grained permissions*

  - privilege is lumped together and assigned at the user level
  - this quickly becomes unmanageable especially when you have hundreds of users
- you *cannot easily revoke privileges* in case of an emergency

  - only manual inspection of each user would reveal who had certain permissions

In the example I gave, if the company detected malicious behaviour on their databases then they could instantly revoke the `DatabaseOperator` role, preventing any further damage. They could then bring in security auditors and let them assume the `ApplicationSecurityAuditor` role to check out the state of the system, removing their access once the audit is completed. Also, if they decide to lock down their databases then that's as easy as removing/disabling the `DatabaseOperator` role or removing destructive abilities from the role.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - i'm quite familiar with the least privileges concept and RBAC based security.
just don't understand something very basic - let's say i continue your example and i have a user which is only allowed to EC2 and S3.  according to what you say he can potentially assume roles which can be harmful . how does the company control which roles he can assume ?

Comment: At the time the company creates the temporary creds for the developer they specify which role can be assumed and that role will have an IAM policy attached specifying what resources it can access. Also, an inline policy can also be attached at this time as well - see the docs on [session policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_session) for more details. So: the role being assumed is limited by its policy; a policy on the STS creds also restricts access; and you limit the ability to assume roles by only giving the creds to those you trust.

Answer (score 3):

You would typically use IAM roles for two things:

1. cross-account access (rather than creating an IAM user for someone in the other account to use in your account)
2. applications, for example running in EC2 or on AWS Lambda

One of the primary benefits of IAM roles is that credentials derived from an IAM role are short-term and will expire. A set of credentials being exposed a few days after they were created becomes a non-issue as they've already expired.

I think the phrase "*use to access AWS resources that you might not normally have access to*" relates mostly to #1 above (cross-account access).

For your situation, I think it's typical to use IAM User credentials and to apply appropriate best practices there, notably secure them properly and rotate them periodically.

For more, read [IAM Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html).

Comment: thanks for that - but can you explain the rational here , i sill need to keep credentials to be able to assume the new IAM role . i understand the use cases - but one still needs an access_key before getting the temporary access key no ?

Comment: Let’s say that you create an IAM role for a certain use case (say reviewing security logs in a specific S3 bucket). Obviously you only want certain people to be able to leverage/assume that role. To do that you need to be able to authenticate those people. How do they authenticate that they are who they claim to be? They use their own IAM credentials.